# Função dentro de uma função

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, método

Estou fazendo uns testes e gostaria de entender o motivo pelo qual quando minha função `somadez()` é chamada é retornado para mim que a função `soma()` não foi definida sendo que a mesma quando é chamada funciona.

Segue o código:

```
class op():
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.x = num1
        self.y = num2

    def soma(self):
        return self.x+self.y

    def somadez(self):
        return soma()+10

conta1 = op(1,2)
print(conta1.soma())
print(conta1.somadez())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não tem um função aí, tem um método, pelo menos pela convenção adotada que se tiver um `self` como parâmetro é um método, então métodos só podem ser chamados através de um objeto, não podem ser chamados de forma direta.

Quando chamou em `conta1.soma()` você chamou por um método, passando o objeto, mas quando chamou por `soma() + 10` não usou objeto algum para passar para o parâmetro `self`. Como o único objeto que você tem dentro do método `somadez()` é o `self` que ele recebeu fica fácil resolver, basta usá-lo como objeto para chamar o método desejado.

```
class op():
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.x = num1
        self.y = num2

    def soma(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def somadez(self):
        return self.soma() + 10

conta1 = op(1, 2)
print(conta1.soma())
print(conta1.somadez())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OZA9Sl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/OrderlyDistantSquare). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/SelfEscope.py).

Note que Python tem um *syntax sugar* que permite chamar o método passando o objeto para o `self` com a notação do objeto antes do método.

Isso nada tem a ver com função dentro de função. è sobre o escopo do `self`, ele não vale para toda classe, ele precisa ser passado explicitamente.

Comment: Obrigado! Esclareceu minhas duvidas!